How to make Fernet accept the key in Python?
I’m trying to do the code that automatically sets a password and encrypts archive, after that it encrypts the keys in AES and then sends it via ftp to another computer. When the computer receives that, it asks for Fernet password and just a password for an archive, that was given. But the thing is there appears to be a problem: when I try to enter the password that is given, Fernet says that something is wrong. Code:
Encryption code:
x = os.urandom(16)
y = Fernet.generate_key()
try:
    with pyzipper.AESZipFile(archname, 'w', compression=pyzipper.ZIP_LZMA) as zip_file:
        # Adding files to the archive
        zip_file.write(filename, arcname=os.path.basename(filename))

        # Setting the password
        zip_file.setpassword(x)  # Устанавливаем пароль
        zip_file.setencryption(pyzipper.WZ_AES, nbits=256)  # Настраиваем AES-шифрование (256 бит)

    print(f"File {filename} successfully added to the archive.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occured: {e}")
    exit(1)

# Cipher (archive)
print("Шифровка: 7/10")
try:
    cipher_suite = Fernet(y)
    with open(archname, 'rb') as file:
        file_data = file.read()
        encrypted_data = cipher_suite.encrypt(file_data)

    with open(archname, 'wb') as afile:
        afile.write(encrypted_data)

    print("Archive is successfully encrypted.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occured: {e}")
    exit(1)
# Cipher (passwords)
key = os.urandom(32)  # 32-byte key for AES-256
iv = os.urandom(16)  # 16-byte IV


cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=default_backend())
aesx = cipher.encryptor().update(x) + cipher.encryptor().finalize()
aesy = cipher.encryptor().update(y) + cipher.encryptor().finalize()

# Printing out them:
print("aesx:", base64.b64encode(aesx).decode())
print("aesy:", base64.b64encode(aesy).decode())
print("key:", base64.b64encode(key).decode())
print("iv:", base64.b64encode(iv).decode())

Decryption code:
def decrypt_data(aesx, aesy, key, iv):
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv))

    # Decoding aesx
    decryptor_for_data = cipher.decryptor()
    x = decryptor_for_data.update(aesx) + decryptor_for_data.finalize()

    # Decoding aesy
    decryptor_for_key = cipher.decryptor()
    y = decryptor_for_key.update(aesy) + decryptor_for_key.finalize()

    return x, y
aesx = base64.b64decode(input("aesx: "))
aesy = base64.b64decode(input("aesy: "))
key = base64.b64decode(input("key: "))
iv = base64.b64decode(input("iv: "))
x, y = decrypt_data(aesx, aesy, key, iv)


print("Decoded key (y):", y)
print("Length of y:", len(y))

y_base64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(y).decode('utf-8')
print("Key (y) in URL-safe Base64 format:", y_base64)
print("Length of key (y) in Base64 format:", len(y_base64))

y_decoded = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(y_base64)
print("Key (y) after decoding in bytes:", y_decoded)
print("The length of key (y):", len(y_decoded))

if y == y_decoded:
    print("Key wasn't modified")
else:
    print("The key was modified!!")

cipher_suite = Fernet(y_decoded)
with open(archname, 'rb') as encrypted_file:
    encrypted_data = encrypted_file.read()
    decrypted_data = cipher_suite.decrypt(encrypted_data)

with open(archname, 'wb') as decrypted_file:
    decrypted_file.write(decrypted_data)

print("Archive was successfully decoded")

Error:
Decoded key (y): b'y0151X8VtqM2zoFq3Mi1EbLd0zUcNBib'
Length of y: 32
Key (y) in URL-safe Base64 format: eTAxNTFYOFZ0cU0yem9GcTNNaTFFYkxkMHpVY05CaWI=
Length of key (y) in Base64 format: 44
Key (y) after decoding in bytes: b'y0151X8VtqM2zoFq3Mi1EbLd0zUcNBib'
The length of key (y): 32
Key wasn't modified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kolya080808/eftp/evsftp.py", line 88, in <module>
    cipher_suite = Fernet(y_decoded)  # Теперь используем строку URL-safe Base64
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/kolya080808/eftp/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 40, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.

I tried to do a lot of thing, like not encoding it in base64 or just giving the key, not aesy one, but it didn't help.
All i want is to know, what did i do wrong :)

Your key is 32 characters long, but it's not 32 base64 encoded bytes long. If you base64 decode the key you printed, you end up with 24 bytes, so you're 8 short (assuming that's what the error means). Instead of catching the exception and printing it, you should remove the try .. except and share the full strack trace with us.

Ok, here you are : )

Right, so you're getting the key from user input (and some juggling through various functions, but it starts with input("key: ")) and you end up with a key that's 32 characters long, but not a base64-encoded 32 byte key - which is the error you're getting directly from Fernet. That is the problem - you could share what input you're providing, but that would just amount to us talking you through what all your code is doing step by step to end up with something that's only a 24 byte key. Why do you think what you have should work? Do you understanding the problem I've pointed out?

Yeah. i understood. So the problem is with the code: it thinks that decoded key from aes is not base64-encoded key but it is. The main reason why i think it should work is that i tried to do the same thing with some other variables (like key, iv) so the type would be correct, and it worked. But as i see Fernet key should be base64-urlsafe-encoded, however Fernet thinks it's not. I can tell you fully how the server and client algorithm works for you to understand it better, if you want.

Removing aes enctyption for the y key helped. But still: if it is possible remain encryption, how can i do so that Fernet accepts it?

The error message says nothing about it specifically not being base64-encoded, and given the characters that are in there, it could well be - it is however not 32 base64-encoded bytes, it's just 24 of them.
